# Python 2.5 subprocess.Popen problem

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to run the following little Python script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.5
import sys, subprocess
child = subprocess.Popen("muscle -stable -FASTA",
                         stdin=sys.stdin,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                         shell=(sys.platform!="win32"))
print child.stderr.read()
print child.stdout.read()
```

Which works fine if `stdin` does not exceed about 3750 characters. Above this limit, the subprocess does no longer produce any `stdout` or `stderr`. If I switch them for `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` respectively, everything works again as expected. The `muscle` executable writes to both `stdout` and `stderr` when called from command-line.

Any suggestions what could be the cause and how to solve this?- best without updating Python, since the installation is on a server I have limited access to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `child.`[`communicate(someinput)`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to get the full output; see the 'warning' boxes in the documentation also. If you really need to read stdin interactively while writing to stdout, then (at least on Windows) you may be out of luck with Python + pipes.

Comment: Thank you, "out, err = child.communicate()" works perfectly. But why I don't understand. For the reason geekosaur explained?

Comment: @user: `communicate` fires up two threads that read `stdout` and `stderr` concurrently. http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/subprocess.py?revision=82075&view=markup

Comment: @user538603: Yes. What's worse, the behavior will probably differ across platforms, etc., so you may not notice deadlock at all (while, say, your client does).  In addition, if you launch multiple subprocesses at once, you'll need `close_fds=True` to ensure that the child processes don't inadvertently start waiting for each other.

Answer (score 3):

Your process is blocked on a full pipe, waiting for you to read from it; since you're busy writing, you have a nice little deadlock.  If you're going to both read and write to the same subprocess, you should use a `select()`-based event loop, reading when output is available and writing when there is room for more data in the input pipe.

Comment: An event-loop seems to be overkill for the thing I'm trying to do. communicate() solved it, but thanks either way.